# Cannot compile rust program due to E0308 error

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to rust and I am trying to build a CLI news tool.
I split out my theme into a separate file and used the `mod theme;` to bring it into scope.

However, I ran into some issues with the colours and attributes of `crossterm` in the `theme.rs` file. I am not sure what is the issue. Am I using bring the module in wrongly?

Also, when I removed the `mod theme;` from the main file, the errors in `theme.rs` goes away. So I am not clear what is the issue.

**Code**

main.rs

```rust
mod theme;

use std::error::Error;
use dotenv::dotenv;

use newsapi::{Articles, get_articles};

fn render_articles(articles: &Articles) {
    let theme = theme::default();
    theme.print_text("# Top headline\n\n");
    for a in &articles.articles {
        theme.print_text(&format!("`{}`", a.title));
        theme.print_text(&format!("> *{}*", a.url));

    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    dotenv()?;

    let api_key = std::env::var("API_KEY")?;
    let url: &str = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=";
    let url = format!("{}{}", url, api_key);
    let articles = get_articles(&url)?;
    
    render_articles(&articles);
    Ok(())
}
```

theme.rs

```
use crossterm::style::{Color::*, Attribute::*};
use termimad::*;

pub fn default() -> MadSkin{
    let mut skin = MadSkin::default();

    skin.bold.set_fg(gray(20));

    skin.strikeout = CompoundStyle::new(Some(Red), None, Bold.into());
    skin
}
```

**Errors**

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/theme.rs:9:46
  |
9 |     skin.strikeout = CompoundStyle::new(Some(Red), None, Bold.into());
  |                                              ^^^ expected enum `crossterm::style::types::color::Color`, found enum `Color`
  |
  = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `crossterm` are being used?
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `crossterm::style::attributes::Attributes: From<Attribute>` is not satisfied
 --> src/theme.rs:9:63
  |
9 |     skin.strikeout = CompoundStyle::new(Some(Red), None, Bold.into());
  |                                                               ^^^^ the trait `From<Attribute>` is not implemented for `crossterm::style::attributes::Attributes`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <crossterm::style::attributes::Attributes as From<&[crossterm::style::types::attribute::Attribute]>>
            <crossterm::style::attributes::Attributes as From<crossterm::style::types::attribute::Attribute>>
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<crossterm::style::attributes::Attributes>` for `Attribute`
```

The code in `theme.rs` is following the example code given in the documentation of `termimad`
https://docs.rs/termimad/0.20.3/x86_64-apple-darwin/termimad/index.html

cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "clinewsapp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
colour = "0.6.0"
newsapi = {path = "./newsapi"}
dotenv = "0.15.0"
termimad = "0.20.3"
crossterm = "0.25.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the compiler's note:

> note: perhaps two different versions of crate `crossterm` are being used?

`termimad` depends on `crossterm` major version `0.23`, but you have probably specified a different major version of `crossterm` in your `Cargo.toml` (I can't be sure, because you did not include it). That results in two different copies of the library being compiled, which doesn't work when you want to pass values from *your* usage of `crossterm` to `termimad`'s.

You will need to downgrade your `crossterm` dependency to `0.23`, or patch `termimad` to use a newer version of `crossterm`. Judging by [previous example](https://github.com/Canop/termimad/issues/29), the author of `termimad` might be happy to accept a patch that updates the `crossterm` dep.

> Also, when I removed the `mod theme;` from the main file, the errors in `theme.rs` goes away.

That's because if there's no `mod`, then `theme.rs` is not part of your project at all, so it is not compiled and no errors will be reported.

Comment: This worked! thanks! Was using the latest version of `crossterm` 0.25

Comment: Termimad author here. There are breaking changes in Crossterm 0.24 and Crossterm 0.25, so you can't just patch termimad by updating the Cargo.toml file. See for example the [compatibility table in another crossterm based library](https://github.com/Canop/crokey#crossterm-compatibility).